# Is there a way in SVN to commit multiple times without updating each time?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I`m coming from git and now I have to use SVN. Is there a way, that I can commit changes in my code without uploading it to the server each time? It would be like:

```
pull something
commit something
/*little bit later*/
pull something
commit something
push
```

so I want to commit multiple changes and upload all changes at once.

Comment: no it is not supported by SVN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cant do it in using tortoise SVN.
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Refer the Above link

> In Git, Developers start by cloning the central repository. In their
>   own local copies of the project, they edit files and commit changes as
>   they would with SVN; however, these new commits are stored
>   locally—they’re completely isolated from the central repository. This
>   lets developers defer synchronizing upstream until they’re at a
>   convenient break point. But in SVN, when we commit changes it will update the central repository

Comment: Ok thanks. Well, i like this feature in git...sad that I have to use SVN.

Comment: You can also try mercurialSCm/ trortoiseHg, if you need a centralised repo

Answer (score 1):

In SVN, you cannot do it.
Do all changes at once(Task) and commit the code to server.